# Flurry analytics not reporting any updates on android

Tags: android, flurry

In my application i have added flurry analytic  but even after days of adding it. i don't see any updates on the dashboard. could any one help me on this. thanks in advance,

```
public static void StartSession(Context context) {
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(context, CommonKeys.APIKey_FLURRY);
    FlurryAgent.onEvent("App Started");
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, CommonKeys.APIKey_FLURRY);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

i am calling the below line on splash

```
BaseActivity.StartSession(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the integration as recommended by the documentation. I have created a `BaseActivity` that will be extended by my activities. This code works for me...

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, Constants.FLURRY_API_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }
}
```

Logs from Flurry can be found in your LogCat and they should look like this:

```
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Initializing Flurry session
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  New session
  4359          TitleActivity  V  ::onResume::
  4359               Settings  W  Setting android_id has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
  4359            FlurryAgent  I  loading persistent data: /data/data/com.xxxxxx/files/.flurryagent.-6ee7b2a3
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Loading API key: ****************KT9C
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Loading session reports
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Persistent file loaded
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  generating report
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Report successful
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Processing report response
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Done sending initial agent report
```

Comment: Check you LogCat, you should see something like that: http://pastebin.com/7SHB8hsi

Comment: If you guys are having trouble getting the logs to show, try make sure these two lines are added: `FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);`
and `FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);`

Answer (score 1):

It's very important you never pass an Application Context to FlurryAgent.onStartSession().  As I recall, you should only ever pass Activity or Service contexts.

Comment: At the very least, this used to be true for Flurry SDK versions from about a year ago. Maybe it's changed now, I don't know.